# Font loads with artifacts

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, fonts

I've recently come on to an error when loading fonts in my game, some letters show up perfect while others have artifacts around them. Here's an example of this:

[image: ???]

While some letters are perfectly normal, others are being unstable.

My options menu:
[image: here]

This is what my loader method looks like. (Yes i've tried other fonts)

```
private static int loadTexture(BufferedImage image) {
        int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;
        int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

        ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * BYTES_PER_PIXEL);

        for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
                int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
                buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));             // Blue component
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));     // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
            }
        }
        buffer.flip();

        int textureID = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        return textureID;
    }
```